# Linker error + Xcode 5.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, linker-errors

I am getting following linker error in my project.

```
Ld /Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestProject.app/TestProject normal i386
    cd /Users/macadmin/Downloads/Medocity/mobile-ios-patient-cancer
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode5.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L../mobile-ios-patient-common/External/RestKit -L../mobile-ios-patient-common/Modules/LiveHelp/lib -L../mobile-ios-patient-common/External/TestFlightSDK2.0.0 -L../mobile-ios-patient-common/External/UrbanAirship -F/Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F../mobile-ios-patient-common/External/FB -F../mobile-ios-patient-common/External -filelist /Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Intermediates/TestProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lxml2 -lUAirship-2.0.0 -lTestFlight -framework IG -framework IGChart -framework FacebookSDK -lRestKit -framework Foundation -lavutil -lspeex -lssl -lxml2 -lswscale -lsqlite3.0 -lSKP_SILK_SDK -lsqlite3 -lzrtpcpp -lspeexdsp -lopencore-amrwb -framework Accounts -framework AdSupport -lsrtp -losip2 -framework CFNetwork -lbcg729 -lvpx -framework CoreText -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -lopencore-amrnb -framework QuartzCore -framework Social -lmediastreamer_voip -losipparser2 -lmsilbc -llinphone -framework SystemConfiguration -lmediastreamer_base -lmsamr -framework CoreBluetooth -lmsx264 -lc++.1 -lavcodec -lresolv -lstdc++.6 -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AssetsLibrary -lx264 -framework AudioToolbox -lcrypto -framework AVFoundation -lgsm -lortp -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -lmsbcg729 -framework GLKit -lz -lmssilk -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -lilbc -framework Security -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreData -leXosip2 -framework UIKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Intermediates/TestProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-bcrdhvfhcafaljdguvbmqdgtmoel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestProject.app/TestProject

ld: library not found for -lmsilbc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using 4-5 third party library in my project like restKit, testflight, IGChart.framework, UrbanAirship.

I have no idea why this error is coming. Please provide me some pointers to solve this issue.

Thanks,

tek3

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917597/restkit-linker-error?rq=1) link may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select the library file in the build phase.

Select Target, then Build Phase then link binary with libraries. then select + then add the library file that is missed out.
Then set the path in the build settings. 
Clean... then Build the project.

Comment: Hi, I  checked in the build phase and all the libraries are added there. I removed and again added all the frameworks and  cleaned the build but still no luck so far.

Comment: did u add library search path in the Build Settings

Answer (score 0):

Add you library in build phase. then how make i: 
Through finder i know where my library inside project folder, i'm create a new folder and put my library files there, then you go "Build settings" -> "Search Path" - > "Library Search Path" and set something like :

```
"$(SRCROOT)/projectName/libraryFolderName"
```

for example:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/test/CorePlot"
```